# Question on dedekind cuts construction in wikipedia

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

The wiki on the [a construction of real numbers by Dedekind cuts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Construction_of_the_real_numbers#Construction_by_Dedekind_cuts) says that negation is defined as :

$ - B := \{a - b: a <0 \land  b \in ( \textbf{Q} \setminus B ) \}$

I don't see how that makes sense. Say, $B = \{x \in \textbf{Q} : x<5 \}$ (i.e. $B$ represents the real number 5). Then {$\textbf{Q}\setminus B\}$ = $\{b \in \textbf{Q} : b>=5 \}$, and so $\{a <0 \} \bigcap  \{b \in ( \textbf{Q} \setminus B ) \} = \emptyset $

But it should be the real number -5 (i.e. $\{x \in \textbf{Q} : x<-5 \}$). Am I misunderstanding something or is the wiki wrong?

Comment: You are misunderstanding. It's the set of differences $a-b$, where $a < 0$ and $b \geqslant 5$ in this case.

Comment: Did you bother with the search function on the site before posting this question? I tend to think that searching for `"dedekind cut" inverse` would find several questions on the topic.